# How to divide sprite into smaller parts in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, sprite

No i don't ask about spritesheets.
I'm working on a game in pygame and I want to know if it's possible to divide sprite into parts like body parts and then use it in collision-detection with pygame.sprite.groupcollide?

Comment: It would be better to have the separate body parts as separate sprites if you need individual collision management.

Comment: You can also use [pygame.mask](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html) - if parts of sprite didn't change location you will need one mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Sprite class has no notion of separate parts of a sprite; the whole thing is assigned a single bounding box. If you plan on using `pygame.sprite.groupcollide` it seems like you don't want an individual sprite anyway, you want them packaged together in their own group. Keep in mind that the `pygame.sprite.Group.add` method can take either a single sprite OR an iterable of sprites. So you can nest sprite groups if necessary.